# How to convert strings separated by comma from base 36 to decimal

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I'm getting input from a google form. An associate scans a QR code giving a string like `^12t34:1`

Cell B1 = `^12t34:1`

The string between the ^ and : is base36. I can use

C1
`=DECIMAL(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(B1,"((?:.*?,)(\^)|:[0-9][0-9]{0,1})", ""), "^", ""),36)` and get 1810624

But associates can scan multiple entries in a single cell like Cell B1 = `^12345:1, ^54321:1, ^ph345:1, ^a4321:1`

using the same formula I get a #NUM! error, so I used a split formula

`=DECIMAL(Split(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(B3,"((?:.*?,)(\^)|:[0-9][0-9]{0,1})", ""), "^", ""),", "),36)`

but it only returns the result for the first entry = 1776965

I'm trying to convert all entries from a single cell containing

`^12345:1, ^54321:1, ^ph345:1, ^a4321:1`

and keep them separated by a comma and space:

`1776965, 8588665, 42787589, 16986745`

Comment: You can use the simpler `=JOIN(", ",ArrayFormula(DECIMAL(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(Q22,"\^|:\d", ""),", "),36)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your formula inside ARRAYFORMULA function. The resulting formula is the following:

`=ArrayFormula(DECIMAL(Split(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(B3,"((?:.*?,)(\^)|:[0-9][0-9]{0,1})", ""), "^", ""),", "),36))`

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I just added a join formula at the beginning to combine them back into a single cell